# Stream a WAV File From The Web In Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, httpwebrequest, silverlight-3.0, webrequest, wavmss

I've managed to discover [Gilles Khouzam's playback implementation](http://blogs.msdn.com/gillesk/archive/2009/03/23/playing-back-wave-files-in-silverlight.aspx) for WAV files in Silverlight 3 and while that would be the majority of the battle, I'm stuck on a final detail: how do I pull a wav file from the web some place and then feed it into his WaveMediaStreamSource for playback?

Here's the closest I've come:

```
    public MainControl()
    {
        // Required to initialize variables
        InitializeComponent();
        PlayButton.Click += PlayButtonClicked;
    }

    private void PlayButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(@"soundfile.wav");
        request.BeginGetResponse(ReadCallback, request); 
    }

    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);

        WaveMediaStreamSource wavMss = new WaveMediaStreamSource(response.GetResponseStream());
        MediaPlayer.SetSource(wavMss);
    }
```

**Edit:**
It turns out the problem had to do with HttpWebRequest. Changing the code to:

```
        public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_OpenReadCompleted);
        webClient.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(@"http://www.russellmyers.com/somefile.wav", UriKind.Absolute));
    }

    void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {


        WaveMediaStreamSource wavMss = new WaveMediaStreamSource(e.Result);
        Debug.WriteLine("Setting source...");
        Media.SetSource(wavMss);
    }
```

Works fine. This makes sense too after reading [Shawn Wildermuth's article on the differences](http://wildermuth.com/2008/09/27/WebClient_vs_WebRequest_in_Silverlight_2). I would like to get HttpWebRequest working though because it won't be done on the UI thread.

Comment: What is not working with this implementation? It looks okay to me. I assume MediaPlayer is a MediaElement, did you try calling MediaPlayer.Play()?

Comment: this is not audio streaming btw