# Streaming a non-PCM WAV file to a SilverLight application

Tags: silverlight, streaming, wav

I would like to allow users to play recorded WAV files that stored on a server back to a Silverlight application as a client to play them.
I saw that there is a way to play a WAV file on Silverlight ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924409/stream-a-wav-file-from-the-web-in-silverlight-3)), but when i tried to impliment it, i got an error playing the file because it is not in PCM format but encoded.

The files that i'm trying to play are encoded with a special encoder, so i thought that the only way is to decode the WAV file on the server and stream it back to the client. The limitation is that the decode process **should occur in real time** because it is not reasonable to convert all the WAV files that exists.

Is it possible to do it? Which streamer can i use? (Windows Media Service can help here?) Does somebody has any experience with such a scenario?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

This example http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,tips.aspx#tip24 "..way via a web page to convert a saved Wav file to MP3.." Converting to PCM even easier. You just need replace AudioCompressionManager.MpegLayer3FormatTag to AudioCompressionManager.PcmFormatTag

Answer (score 0):

you would be best off streaming as MP3 since PCM WAV is very inefficient. You should check out [Sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/), which may well be able to perform the conversion you require on the fly.